How to pass a string as an argument of defun on elisp
This elisp code, which I written on init.el, intended as xref buffer pop-up only takes 30% of the screen, works well.
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
               '("\\*xref\\*"
                 (display-buffer-in-side-window)
                 (window-height . 0.3)
                 (side . bottom)))

However when I try it to define as a defun like this, It goes wrong and does not works.
(defun m/set-buffer-pop-height (buffer height)
  (add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
               '(buffer
                 (display-buffer-in-side-window)
                 (window-height . height)
                 (side . bottom))))
(m/set-buffer-pop-height "\\*xref\\*" 0.3)
(m/set-buffer-pop-height "\\*eldoc\\*" 0.3)

What did I do wrong? There was no compilation warning or error.
I tried this to pass the (buffer ...) as an list, it does not works either.
(defun m/set-buffer-pop-height (buffer height)
  (add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
               (list buffer
                     '(display-buffer-in-side-window)
                     (cons 'window-height height)
                     (cons 'side 'bottom))))

